# I can't find the create xml option while trying to create a new layout in android project

Tags: android, xml, eclipse

I am trying to create a new layout in the layout folder of the res, but the xml file option is not available. I have attached a link below.
[image]

Comment: images are not visible dude.

Comment: new -> other -> xmlLayout

Comment: new->other ->android->Android xml layout file

Comment: it just has DTD file, XML schema File and DTD file

Comment: you can use 8th short cut too, from left

Comment: for your comment i need to say, you try looking on XML section, but you need create new XML Layout on android section

Answer (score 0):

Try updating the Eclipse plugin:

```
Eclipse --> Help --> Install new software -->
```

Pasted URL: http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/